# Partitions in Proc SQL

Tags: sas

Can we use partitions inside Proc Sql, if not could you please help me the equivalent logic to use?

```
Proc sql;
select user_id,
       content_title,
       calendar_date,
       sum(watch_second)/3600 as hours_watched,
       sum(hours_watched) over (partition by user_id, content_title order by calendar_date) AS cumulative_hours,
       available_hours,
       cumulative_hours / available_hours as pct_completed
                from watch_history as a
                inner join dim_user s
                ON s.USER_ID = a.USER_ID
                left join dim_content_meta pb
                 ON pb.metrics_video_id = a.metrics_video_id
                inner join sascidm.coop_top50 v
                 on pb.hummus_show_id = v.hummus_show_id
                where pb.hummus_playback_type in ('VOD')
                  AND pb.hummus_show_type = 'series'
                order by 1,2,3;

quit;
```

Error:

```
sum(watch_second)/3600 as hours_watched,
29                sum(hours_watched) over (partition by user_id, content_title order by calendar_date) AS cumulative_hours,
                                     ____
                                     22
                                     76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Comment: PROC SQL only supports SQL syntax of ANSI 1992 standard.

Answer (score 0):

No, `proc sql` supports only a relatively limited set of SQL that's close to ANSI SQL from a few decades ago, and does not support `partition by` as that's much newer.

For the most part, a SAS programmer would instead use SAS procs to compute things like this rather than SQL - PROC TABULATE could probably do this I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple in a DATA step to generate a cummulative sum.  Just use a SUM statement. To reset by groups use a FIRST. flags to detect when a new group is starting.

```
Proc sql;
create table raw as
select
  user_id
 ,content_title
 ,calendar_date
 ,sum(watch_second)/3600 as hours_watched
/*
 ,sum(hours_watched) over (partition by user_id, content_title order by calendar_date) AS cumulative_hours
*/
 ,available_hours
/*
 ,cumulative_hours / available_hours as pct_completed
*/
from watch_history as a
inner join dim_user s
  ON s.USER_ID = a.USER_ID
left join dim_content_meta pb
  ON pb.metrics_video_id = a.metrics_video_id
inner join sascidm.coop_top50 v
  on pb.hummus_show_id = v.hummus_show_id
where pb.hummus_playback_type in ('VOD')
  AND pb.hummus_show_type = 'series'
order by 1,2,3
;
quit;

data want;
  set raw ;
  by user_id content_title calendar_date;
  if first.content_title then cumulative_hours=0;
  cumulative_hours + hours_watched;
  pct_completed = cumulative_hours / available_hours;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried, it did not work. Could you please explain me the data step here. This specific step 'cumulative_hours + hours_watched; ' is not giving me anything, it is just a blank field.

Comment: Read the SAS documentation on the SUM statement. The SUM statement will only work when making a NEW variable.    CUMULATIVE_HOURS will be set to 0 on the first observation of each new CONTENT_TITLE value and that value will be retained forward incrementing by the value of HOURS_WATCHED as each new CALENDAR_DATE row is processed.  The only way the posted code could create a missing value for CUMULATIVE_HOURS is if the variable HOURS_WATCHED is missing AND the variable CUMULATIVE_HOURS mistakenly already exists in RAW and is also missing.